# Importing files with different months in name

Tags: regex, stata, stata-macros

I have the following code:

```
local date "September"

global dir `c(pwd)'
global files "A B C" 

foreach x of global files { 
    import excel "${path}`x'_`date'.xlsx", sheet("1") cellrange(A3:O21) clear 
    generate Store="`x'"
    save `x', replace
}
```

The problem is that not all my files have the date `September`. Some have `August` or `May`.

How can I incorporate a solution for this in the above script?

The idea is that if `September` is not found, the code would still run. However, instead of `September` it would go for `August` and if that fails, then `May`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the following files are stored in your working directory:

```
A_September.xlsx
B_August.xlsx
C_May.xlsx
```

You can use the macro extended function `dir` and wildcards to create a local 
macro `files`, which will contain a list of qualifying files:

```
local files : dir "`c(pwd)'" files "*_*.xlsx"                               

foreach x of local files {
    display "`x'"
}

A_September.xlsx
B_August.xlsx
C_May.xlsx
```

Typing `help extended_fcn` from Stata's command prompt will provide you with
more information.

Suppose now that in your working directory there are two additional files:

```
ASeptember_34.xlsx
C_May45.xlsx
```

In this case, the files will be included in the list:

```
local files : dir "`c(pwd)'" files "*_*.xlsx"                               

foreach x of local files {
    display "`x'"
}

A_September.xlsx
ASeptember_34.xlsx
B_August.xlsx
C_May.xlsx
C_May45.xlsx
```

In order to ignore these in your loop, you need to further filter
the file names using a regular expression:

```
local files : dir "`c(pwd)'" files "*_*.xlsx"                               

foreach x of local files {
    if ustrregexm("`x'", "[A-Z]_([A-Z][a-z]+).xlsx") display "`x'"
}

A_September.xlsx
B_August.xlsx
C_May.xlsx
```

Note that the complexity of the required regular expression will depend on the
patterns of the file names included in your working directory.